# I can't launch ipython-listener

Tags: python, ide, ipython, gedit

I'm trying to get up and running with an [ipython plugi](https://github.com/smathot/gedit-plugin-ipython/blob/master/README)n for gedit3, but it requires `ipython-listener`, and when I try to launch it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython-listener", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed
ImportError: No module named terminal.embed
```

I'm running ipython version 0.10.2 and python version 2.7.2+

I tried to do `pip install terminal.embed` but couldn't find it:

```
Downloading/unpacking terminal.embed
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement terminal.embed
No distributions at all found for terminal.embed
Storing complete log in /home/amanda/.pip/pip.log
```

So now what?

Comment: Since I end up back here from time to time, here's how I launch `ipython-listener` in a clean terminal with a custom title/coloring: `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=light --title=iPython --execute ipython-listener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to do `pip install terminal.embed` but couldn't find it

It's not a package, it's part of IPython.  Your IPython is just too old (by a couple of years).

That plugin depends on IPython ≥ 0.11 (current is 0.13.1).  Try:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
```